# bootstrap div alignment broke on small device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to layout responsive divs. 
Basically I'm trying to achieve this view.

for large desktop:

```
 __ _______ __ 
|  |  2.1  |  |
|1 |_______|3 |
|  |2.2|2.3|  |
|__|___|___|__|
```

for tablet:

```
    ______________
   |______1_______|
   |     2.1      |
   |______________|
   | 2.2  | 2.3   |
   |______|_______|
   |______3_______|
```

lastly for small devices such as phone:

```
    ______________
   |______1_______|
   |     2.1      |
   |______________|
   |     2.2      |
   |______________|
   |     2.3      |
   |______________|
   |______3_______|
```

and corresponding html with bootstrap is following:

```
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-sm"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-sm"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-sm"></div>
    </div>
```

For desktop and tablet case, it worked as I expected. But layout was broken on small case. It showed something like this

```
    ______________
   |______1_______|
   |     2.1      |
   |______________|
   |     2.2      |
   |______________|
   |______3_______|      
   |_____2.3______|
```

It looked like column 3 was on top of 2.3. I'm still trying to learn bootstrap/css, so any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im quite sure that ur phone is not big enough to be targeted with small devices grid layout as it is working only for media more than 768px wide. The class you are looking for is `col-xs`. Here you have detailed explanation of bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Didn't fix the problem even though I changed to xs. Thanks for pointing out tho

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are adding all of that unnecessary markup. Bootstrap takes care of all of the floating and clearing for each viewport.

This is how I would have written the code to get the layout you want:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<!--end col-->
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>2.1</h1>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>2.2</h1>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>2.3</h1>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
</div>
<!--end col8-->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <!--end col-->
</div>
<!--end row-->
</div>
<!--end container-fluid-->
```

[VIEW DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/c7gm56dx/)